# Where is s3-dist-cp of EMR 6.2.0?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I created an EMR Spark cluster with the following configuration:

[image]

Then I ssh into the master node, typed the command `s3-dist-cp`, then got the following error:

```sh
s3-dist-cp: command not found
```

I searched the whole disk but found nothing:

```sh
sudo find / -name "*s3-dist-cp*"
```

Where is the `s3-dist-cp` command? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I must select "Hadoop", see the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: fyi adding hive also seems to make the binary available